# Primefaces hide and unhide dialog

Tags: primefaces

right now I'm studying the primefaces the UI is incredible and I want to use it to build my website so right now I'm studying the dialog box and I want to hide and unhide dialog box using the requestcontext of the primefaces how can I achieve this? I search the stackoverflow for the same question and I found a few but it is not working on me, to make everything clear this is my register.jsf code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:panel toggleable="true" header="Registration" closable="true" closeTitle="back" styleClass="register-panel">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel  value="Firstname: " />
                <p:inputText id="firstname" value="#{ register.firstName }" required="true" requiredMessage="Firstname cannot be blank">
                    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="3" maximum="15"  />
                </p:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel value="Middlename: " />
                <p:inputText id="middlename" value="#{ register.middleName }" required="true" requiredMessage="Middlename cannot be blank">
                    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="3" maximum="15"  />
                </p:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel value="Lastname: " />
                <p:inputText id="lastname" value="#{ register.lastName }" required="true" requiredMessage="Lastname cannot be blank">
                    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="3" maximum="15"  />
                </p:inputText>

                <p:commandButton type="button" update="errorFirst, errorMiddle, errorLast, ErrorD, confirmD" value="Register" actionListener="#{ register.Register }" />

                <p:dialog width="350"  modal="true" id="ErrorD" header="Error Registration" visible="true" maximizable="false"  widgetVar="showErrorDialog">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <p:message for="firstname" id="errorFirst" />
                    <p:message for="middlename" id="errorMiddle" />
                    <p:message for="lastname" id="errorLast" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>

                <p:dialog width="350" modal="true" id="confirmD" header="Confirm Registration"  visible="true" maximizable="false"  widgetVar="showConfirmDialog">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Are you sure you want to save the records" />
                        <h:outputLabel value=""/>
                        <p:separator />
                        <p:separator />

                        <p:commandButton value="Ok, Sure" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" />
                    </h:panelGrid>

                </p:dialog>

            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and this is my register bean:

```
    package org.register;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.*;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

@ManagedBean(name="register")
@RequestScoped
public class registerBean {

    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }
    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void Register(ActionEvent e){
        RequestContext primeContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if(getFirstName().equals("") || getMiddleName().equals("") || getLastName().equals("")){
            primeContext.execute("showErrorDialog.show()");
        }
        else{
            primeContext.execute("showConfirmDialog.show()");
        }

    }


}
```

I don't have any error on my code but the problem is everytime the page load, it call already the 2 dialog, what I want to do is open the first dialog if registration fail and open the second dialog when it is success. thanks guys.

Comment: `visible="true"` will make the dialogs appear right after the page load, is there any special reason you specified that attribute? `getFirstName().equals("")` in your backing bean is equal to `required="true"` on your `p:inputText`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the code should work by removing `type="button"` in the Register `commandButton`, in order to use an ajax request. the method #{register.Register} was not even called.
Also remove the `visible="true"` in both dialogs

Just as a side note, in order to execute the backing method, JSF executes the validations rules, so you will see the `confirmD` dialog appear only when all the data in the form fulfill such validations